# session_set_save_handler causing login loop

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to write sessions to database using `session_set_save_handler()`. I'm getting an infinite loop, where my system wants to log me in, but cannot find the session, so it logs me out... but the session exists apparently - just not in the table.

Anyway, here's my code for the session functions - I don't think there's anything wrong here:

```
<?php

// session.functions.php

$db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass", "db");
// define 'openSession()' function
function openSession($sessionPath, $sessionName) {
    return true;
}

// define 'closeSession()' function
function closeSession() {
    return true;
}

// define 'readSession()' method
function readSession($sessionId) {
    global $db;
    // escape session ID
        $sessionId = $db->real_escape_string($sessionId);
    $result = $db->query("SELECT sessiondata FROM sessions WHERE
sessionid='$sessionId' AND expiry > NOW()");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetchRow();
        return $row['sessiondata'];
    }
    // return empty string
    return "";
}

// define 'writeSession()' function
function writeSession($sessionId, $sessionData) {
    global $db;
    $expiry = time() + get_cfg_var('session.gc_maxlifetime') - 1;
    // escape session ID & session data
        $sessionId = $db->real_escape_string($sessionId);
        $sessionData = $db->real_escape_string($sessionData);
    $result = $db->query("SELECT sessionid FROM sessions WHERE
sessionid='$sessionId'");
    // check if a new session must be stored or an existing one must be updated 
    ($result->num_rows > 0) ? $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET     sessionid='$sessionId',expiry='$expiry',sessiondata=
'$sessionData' WHERE sessionid='$sessionId'") or die(mysqli_error($db)) : $db->query("INSERT INTO sessions (sessionid,expiry,sessiondata) VALUES ('$sessionId','$expiry','$sessionData')") or die(mysqli_error($db));
    return true;
}

// define 'destroySession()' function
function destroySession($sessionId) {
    global $db;
    // escape session ID
        $sessionId = $db->real_escape_string($sessionId);
    $db->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sessionid='$sessionId'");
    return true;
}

// define 'gcSession()' function
function gcSession($maxlifetime) {
    global $db;
    $db->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE expiry < NOW()");
    return true;
}

?>
```

This is the session setting for login:

```
$this->set_session(array_merge($rs->fetch_assoc(), array('expires' => time() + (15 * 60))));
```

set by function:

```
private function set_session($a=false) {
    if (!empty($a)) {
        $_SESSION['exp_user'] = $a;
    }
}
```

How does my login system check to see if I'm already logged in?

```
public function check_status() {
    if (empty($_SESSION['exp_user']) || @$_SESSION['exp_user']['expires'] < time()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Turns out, the value of $_SESSION, according to var_dump is array(0) { }

and the check in the web application itself:

```
// This is in authorisation.php

if(empty($_SESSION['exp_user']) || @$_SESSION['exp_user']['expires'] < time()) {
        header("location:/login.php");  //@ redirect 
} else {
    $_SESSION['exp_user']['expires'] = time()+(15*60);  //@ renew 15 minutes
        //echo $SID = session_id();
}
```

Now, this is what I have in that index.php file at the top:

```
require('includes/session.functions.php');
session_set_save_handler('openSession', 'closeSession', 'readSession', 'writeSession', 'destroySession', 'gcSession');
session_start();
include('includes/authorisation.php');
```

Here's the database:

[image: SQL Schema]

If I comment out `session_set_save_handler()`, we don't get the loop, however, if I keep it there in action, I get the loop between index and the login system (already logged in -> index ::check login loop.)

```
print_r(session_set_save_handler('openSession', 'closeSession', 'readSession', 'writeSession', 'destroySession', 'gcSession')); == 1 

var_dump(session_set_save_handler('openSession', 'closeSession', 'readSession', 'writeSession', 'destroySession', 'gcSession')); == bool(true)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You database schema is missing. Plus a tutorial: [Storing Sessions in a Database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database)

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and database escaping are two different topics. Don't mix them.

Comment: Added database schema and removed get_magic_quotes_gpc() from code.

Comment: Check the return value of `session_set_save_handler`, it will return FALSE if it failed, TRUE on success.

Comment: bool(true) or 1. It works, apparently, checked with print_r and var_dump

Comment: Okay, fine. Onto the next: You need to escape the `$sessionData` next to the id when you write it into the database.

Comment: Just changed that in the script :)

Comment: So to better debug, remove the redirect header. Just print out a link instead an a message. Then `exit;` to stop execution at that point (do so as well with header). Then `var_dump` the `$_SESSION` before the if. This will give you more info and you would not loop automatically.

Comment: ok, the value of $_SESSION, according to var_dump is array(0) { }

Comment: If the session is correctly stored in the database (check that sessiondata actually contains something), then reading has faild. If the data is empty in the database for the session, then writing has failed.

Comment: It looks to me, like writing has failed: call to non-member function for escaping $sessionID.

Comment: Looks like the global database object is already destroyed when that function is called. I wonder why a bit, maybe you unset that `$db` variable somewhere? This is some other important note [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php): *Note:

    The "write" handler is not executed until after the output stream is closed. Thus, output from debugging statements in the "write" handler will never be seen in the browser. If debugging output is necessary, it is suggested that the debug output be written to a file instead.*

Comment: Nopem $db is NEVER unset, I've even redefined it in sessions.functions.php

Comment: Here's what I've found: Notice: Undefined variable: sessionId in /home/erp/public_html/includes/session.functions.php on line 35. It's writing to the database perfectly - (checked by entering arbitrary data using function).

Comment: Check line 35, your code here has no line numbers.

Comment: Line 35 is $sessionId = $db->real_escape_string($sessionId);

Comment: It's getting later over here, good luck for your further debugging.

Comment: Thanks hakre, it's 12:26 here :/

Comment: xref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418856/call-to-a-member-function-real-escape-string-on-a-non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was an extra session_start(), which would reset the session.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing up two different time formats. In mysql, [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) gives you a time in the format:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

In php, [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gives you:

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

In your sql statements you are comparing the two and you can´t as they are completely different formats.

Comment: fixed in script on server. No dice.