# Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error:

> Call to a member function
>   real_escape_string() on a non-object

and here's `$db`

> $db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "sch5400");

in code:

```
function readSession($sessionId) {
    global $db;
    $sessionId = session_id();
    // escape session ID
    $sessionId = $db->real_escape_string($sessionId);
    $time = time();
    $result = $db->query("SELECT sessiondata FROM sessions WHERE sessionid='$sessionId' AND expiry > $time");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetchRow();
        return $row['sessiondata'];
    }
    // return empty string
    return "";
    }
```

It appears on line 5, relative to code above. Didn't I instantiate `$db`?

Comment: yes. seems there was no $db before.

Comment: *Didn't I instantiate $db*? Don't know. Did you?

Comment: @Shamil: php has an oppositie opinion

Comment: It did, but I've corrected the code excerpt.

Comment: @Shamil: now you know why `global` *is* bad

Comment: I know :( - I can't keep repeating $db in each function though :o

Comment: Why would you need to repeat it in each function?

Comment: The other functions use $db->real_escape_query and other $db as well.

Comment: @Shamil: create a *function that returns `$db`*. And use it like `$db = get_my_db();` in every single function that needs db object

Comment: You set your connection variable once. If you have several connections (to different dbs), then you use different variables for them (like $db1, $db2 and so on).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably the better solution would be to create a singleton function:

```
function get_my_db()
{
    static $db;

    if (!$db) {
        $db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "sch5400");
    }

    return $db;
}
```

and use it like

```
$db = get_my_db();
```

in every function that needs db instance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I'd then reference it to do the real_escape_string check.

Comment: @Shamil: just replace `global $db;` with `$db = get_my_db();` and use it as usually

Comment: @ZERKMS: THANKS FOR THIS SOLUTION - I would recommend it to everyone because of strange issue I have on my php with session handlers. On my php - although I gave global variable for storing mysqli connection it disappears somehow between callbacks calls and the only way to keep one connection and things working was to store connection as local static as shown above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized `$db` anywhere in the code that's shown, and from the error it sounds like it hasn't been initialized anywhere else (yet) either.

If you are initializing `$db` *somewhere*, make sure it's *before* `readSession` is called. Also check for an error message when you make the connection. It returns `false` on error, which is not an object.

from the PHP manual, you should using one of these error checking methods to ensure the connection is established successfully:

```
/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I had it earlier in the file... well right above it in fact.

Comment: Well, not actually. He might have initialized but **has rewritten** it somewhere else

Comment: Ok, bemace removed my SQL query, but I assume you, it's there. I've even put it within the function.

Comment: @shamil can you post the code that creates the database connection?

Answer (score -1):

There is also a global function that doesnt require a db reference.

```
$sessionId = mysql_real_escape_string($sessionId);
```

http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Why do you think OP has valid mysql connection done by `mysql_connect`? Btw, **all** functions in php are global.

Comment: I use $db->real_escape_string with several other things, and they're fine :o